# RxSwift Error: Property 'text' requires that 'UITextField' inherit from 'UILabel'

Tags: ios, xcode, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

```
func bindSearchTextField() {
        searchTextField.rx.text.asObservable().skip(3)
            .debounce(0.3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] searchText in
                guard let strongSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                if let text = searchText {
                    if text == "" {
                        self?.hideLoader()
                        self?.clearButton.isHidden = true
                    } else {
                        self?.clearButton.isHidden = false
                    }
                    strongSelf.presenter?.getAreaCodeList(text: text)
                }
            }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

I'm getting this error after i updated my RxSwift to latest version (from 4.4.0 to 5.1.1).
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `.debounce(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)` instead. The `debounce(_:scheduler:)` that takes a Double has been removed.

Also, you are doing too much in your subscribe. You are better off if you break the subscribe up into independent units:

```
let searchText = searchTextField.rx.text.asObservable().skip(3)
    .debounce(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .compactMap { $0 }

searchText
    .map { $0.isEmpty }
    .bind(to: clearButton.rx.isHidden)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

searchText
    .bind { [presenter] in
        presenter?.getAreaCodeList(text: $0)
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. It helped me with the error and formatted the code as you suggested.